# Can I add a child domain to an existing child domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Under a root domain i have 2 child domains. What I want to do is to create a child domain using an existing child domain as its parent domain, but it's currently giving me credential errors. Do I need to use the (child domain that's going to act as a parent) IP as my DNS Server or the root's IP as my DNS Sever?(currently doing the latter)

This is the structure i'm going for
root/parent: (abc.com) ,
child: (d.abc.com) ,
child i want to add now: (e.d.abc.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally possible to create child/child/child domains, but you will need the *forest's* admins credentials to do that. Just the child-domains domain admin is not enough.